# Unable to Post request via API using PowerShell

Tags: .net, api, powershell

We have a function, that helps post back to an application we run when called. This works perfectly when a client is running PowerShell v3.0 or higher, however we have a hybrid estate and there is no feasibility to upgrade PowerShell just now. I have seen you can use .NET to post xml in the same way, however i cannot get this to work.

Here is the version that works:

```
function SetTaskRealTimeStatus()
{
    param($pRealTimeStatusId, $pResourceGuid, $pNewStatus)

    $url = 'http://server001/myappname/api/resource/';
    $url = $url +  $pResourceGuid + '/task/' + $realTimeStatusId + '/status/'+ $pNewStatus;

    Write-Host ("Sending request: $url") ;

    # Returns Guid of task history record that is created. Empty guid means db call failed
    # Invalid inputs will return BadRequest response
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Method Post
}
```

Here is my version that does not work:

```
function SetTaskRealTimeStatus()
{
    param($pRealTimeStatusId, $pResourceGuid, $pNewStatus)

    $url = 'http://server001/myappname/api/resource/';
    $urlCombined = $url +  $pResourceGuid + '/task/' + $pRealTimeStatusId + '/status/'+ $pNewStatus;

    Write-Host ("Sending request: $urlCombined") ;

    # Returns Guid of task history record that is created. Empty guid means db call failed
    # Invalid inputs will return BadRequest response

    #Used for PowerShell version 2.0
    $WebRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("$urlCombined")
    $WebRequest.Method = "POST"
    $WebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml"
    $WebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
    $Response = $WebRequest.GetResponse() 
    $ResponseStream = $Response.GetResponseStream()
    $ReadStream = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $ResponseStream
    $Data=$ReadStream.ReadToEnd()
    $Request.Timeout = 10000;

    #Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlCombined -Method Post
}
```

The parameters past to the function work fine, as they work with the first version.

Comment: Any error message? What is the content of the params when sending them to the function?

Comment: No error messages, no update in web app.

 # Get custom Computer Id token (SELECT %COMPUTERID%), passed by altiris hosting the script
 $resourceGuid = "%COMPUTERID%";
 # Get RealTimeStatus Id. This is passed into script from application
 $realTimeStatusId =  "%!_APPPARAM_REALTIMESTATUSID!%";
 $currentStatus = "Working on powershell script"


I have outed them to a text file. In this instance they were set to:
d02fbf0e-588e-4ef0-afea-cea28d4ebdda
a99c99b1-3bc5-e711-80ce-005056bb137a
Started PS1

It shows a PS window, looks like the script works fine but does not update via API

Comment: Sorry i should add the powershell prompt stays open, and does not exit correctly, so it may be waiting on an open stream, not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the function working as required:

```
function SetTaskRealTimeStatus()
{

    param($setID, $pResourceGuid, $pNewStatus)


    $url = 'http://server001/myapplication/api/resource/';
    $urlCombined = $url +  $pResourceGuid + '/task/' + $setID + '/status/' + $pNewStatus;

    Write-Host ("Sending request: $urlCombined") ;

    # Returns Guid of task history record that is created. Empty guid means db call failed
    # Invalid inputs will return BadRequest response

    #Used for PowerShell version 2.0

    $WebRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("$urlCombined")
    $body = "$pNewStatus"
    $encodedContent = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($body)
    $WebRequest.Method = "POST"
    $WebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml"
    $WebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
    $requestStream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream()
    $requestStream.Write($encodedContent, 0, $encodedContent.length)  
    [System.Net.WebResponse] $response = $webRequest.GetResponse();
    $response.close()
    $requestStream.Close()


    #used for PowerShell Version 3.0 and above
    #Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlCombined -Method Post
}
```